# Convert tuple to pair

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, std

Have educational task: write template function, which takes arbitrary `std::tuple` and 2 indexes inside and returns `std::pair`, containing elements of given `std::tuple` with correspondent indexes.

**Example:**

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(0, 3.5, "Hello");
std::pair<double, char const *> p = to_pair<1,2>(t);
// p contains 3.5 and "Hello"
```

Written something like this:

```
template<int I, int J>
auto to_pair(std::tuple t) -> decltype(std::make_pair(std::get<I>(t), std::get<J>(t))) {
    return std::make_pair(std::get<I>(t), std::get<J>(t));
}
```

However got an error:

```
r: missing template arguments before ‘t’
auto to_pair(std::tuple t) -> decltype(std::make_pair(get<I>t, get<J>t))
                        ^
```

What I'm doing wrong and what is correct syntax here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::tuple` is a template class, so there's no `std::tuple`, only `std::tuple<T, ...>`. In your case, the type of `t` is `std::tuple<int, double, char const *>`.

Also, you're calling `std::get` without an argument (there's missing braces).

You're almost there, the function should be something along the lines of:

```
template<int I, int J, class... T>
auto to_pair(std::tuple<T...> t)
    -> decltype(std::make_pair(std::get<I>(t), std::get<J>(t))) {
  return std::make_pair(std::get<I>(t), std::get<J>(t));
}
```

Comment: `std::tuple<T, ...>` - very simple thanks, this works!